# Working with intPtr and marshaling using add-type in powershell

Tags: powershell, struct, powershell-2.0, marshalling, add-type

I am experimenting with `add-type` in Powershell.  I am working with [`NetSessionEnum` Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmshare/nf-lmshare-netsessionenum) using `netapi32.dll`.
This almost works but not quite.  When querying with level zero I can get a result.  When querying with any other options the IDE or powershell session simply crashes when trying to marshall `PtrToStructure`. I am completely stuck

I think this is something to do with structure sizes but an not really sure.
If someone could point me in the right direction or offer some tips that would be fantastic.

```powershell
function Get-NetSessions {

param(
[string]$ComputerName = "",
[string]$ComputerSession = "",
[string]$UserName = "",
[int]$QueryLevel

)

$DebugPreference = 'continue'

$signature = @'
[DllImport("netapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int NetSessionEnum(
        [In,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string ServerName,
        [In,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string UncClientName,
        [In,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string UserName,
        Int32 Level,
        out IntPtr bufptr,
        int prefmaxlen,
        ref Int32 entriesread,
        ref Int32 totalentries,
        ref Int32 resume_handle);
'@




$SessionInfoStructures = @'
namespace pinvoke {
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct SESSION_INFO_0
    {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public String sesi0_cname;
    }
        
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct SESSION_INFO_1
    {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string sesi1_cname;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string sesi1_username;
    public uint sesi1_num_opens;
    public uint sesi1_time;
    public uint sesi1_idle_time;
    public uint sesi1_user_flag;
    }
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct SESSION_INFO_2
    {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string sesi2_cname;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string sesi2_username;
    public uint  sesi2_num_opens;
    public uint  sesi2_time;
    public uint  sesi2_idle_time;
    public uint  sesi2_user_flags;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string sesi2_cltype_name;
    }
    
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct SESSION_INFO_10
    {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string sesi10_cname;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string sesi10_username;
    public uint sesi10_time;
    public uint sesi10_idle_time;
    }
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct SESSION_INFO_502
    {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string sesi502_cname;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string sesi502_username;
    public uint sesi502_num_opens;
    public uint sesi502_time;
    public uint sesi502_idle_time;
    public uint sesi502_user_flags;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string sesi502_cltype_name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string sesi502_transport;
    }

    public enum NERR
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Operation was a success.
    /// </summary>
    NERR_Success = 0,
    /// <summary>
    /// More data available to read. dderror getting all data.
    /// </summary>
    ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234,
    /// <summary>
    /// Network browsers not available.
    /// </summary>
    ERROR_NO_BROWSER_SERVERS_FOUND = 6118,
    /// <summary>
    /// LEVEL specified is not valid for this call.
    /// </summary>
    ERROR_INVALID_LEVEL = 124,
    /// <summary>
    /// Security context does not have permission to make this call.
    /// </summary>
    ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5,
    /// <summary>
    /// Parameter was incorrect.
    /// </summary>
    ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87,
    /// <summary>
    /// Out of memory.
    /// </summary>
    ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY = 8,
    /// <summary>
    /// Unable to contact resource. Connection timed out.
    /// </summary>
    ERROR_NETWORK_BUSY = 54,
    /// <summary>
    /// Network Path not found.
    /// </summary>
    ERROR_BAD_NETPATH = 53,
    /// <summary>
    /// No available network connection to make call.
    /// </summary>
    ERROR_NO_NETWORK = 1222,
    /// <summary>
    /// Pointer is not valid.
    /// </summary>
    ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE_STATE = 1609,
    /// <summary>
    /// Extended Error.
    /// </summary>
    ERROR_EXTENDED_ERROR= 1208,
    /// <summary>
    /// Base.
    /// </summary>
    NERR_BASE = 2100,
    /// <summary>
    /// Unknown Directory.
    /// </summary>
    NERR_UnknownDevDir = (NERR_BASE + 16),
    /// <summary>
    /// Duplicate Share already exists on server.
    /// </summary>
    NERR_DuplicateShare = (NERR_BASE + 18),
    /// <summary>
    /// Memory allocation was to small.
    /// </summary>
    NERR_BufTooSmall = (NERR_BASE + 23)
    }
    
    public enum SESSION_LEVEL
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// ZERO
    /// </summary>
    LEVEL_0 = 0,
    /// <summary>
    /// ONE
    /// </summary>
    LEVEL_1 = 1,
    /// <summary>
    /// TWO
    /// </summary>
    LEVEL_2 = 2,
    /// <summary>
    /// TEN
    /// </summary>
    LEVEL_10 = 10,
    /// <summary>
    /// FIVE HUNDRED AND TWO
    /// </summary>
    LEVEL_502 = 502
    }
}
'@



# Add the custom structures and enums
Add-Type $SessionInfoStructures


# Add the function definition
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name Win32Util -Namespace Pinvoke -Using Pinvoke


if ([Pinvoke.SESSION_LEVEL]::LEVEL_0 -eq $QueryLevel) {$x = New-Object pinvoke.SESSION_INFO_0}
if ([Pinvoke.SESSION_LEVEL]::LEVEL_1 -eq $QueryLevel) {$x = New-Object pinvoke.SESSION_INFO_1}
if ([Pinvoke.SESSION_LEVEL]::LEVEL_2 -eq $QueryLevel) {$x = New-Object pinvoke.SESSION_INFO_2}
if ([Pinvoke.SESSION_LEVEL]::LEVEL_10 -eq $QueryLevel) {$x = New-Object pinvoke.SESSION_INFO_10}
if ([Pinvoke.SESSION_LEVEL]::LEVEL_502 -eq $QueryLevel) {$x = New-Object pinvoke.SESSION_INFO_502}

# Declare the reference variables
$type = $x.gettype()
Write-Debug "$type.tostring()"

$ptrInfo = 0 
$EntriesRed = 0
$TotalRead = 0
$ResumeHandle = 0

# Call the function
$Result = [pinvoke.Win32Util]::NetSessionEnum($ComputerName,$ComputerSession,$UserName,0,[ref]$ptrInfo,-1,[ref]$EntriesRed,[ref]$TotalRead,[ref]$ResumeHandle)

$Result


if ($Result -eq ([pinvoke.NERR]::NERR_Success)){

    Write-Debug 'Result is success'
    Write-Debug "IntPtr $ptrInfo"
    Write-Debug "Entries read $EntriesRed"
    Write-Debug "Total Read $TotalRead"


    # Locate the offset of the initial intPtr
    $offset = $ptrInfo.ToInt64()
    Write-Debug "Starting Offset $offset"

    # Work out how mutch to increment the pointer by finding out the size of the structure
    $Increment = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::SizeOf($x)
    Write-Debug "Increment $Increment"


    for ($i = 0; ($i -lt $EntriesRed); $i++){

        $newintptr = New-Object system.Intptr -ArgumentList $offset
        Write-Debug "Newintptr `[$i`] $newintptr"
        $Info = [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::PtrToStructure($newintptr,$type)
        $Info | Select-Object *
        $offset = $newintptr.ToInt64()
        $offset += $increment
    }

}
else 
{
    #       switch ($Result)
    #           {
    #           ([Pinvoke.NERR]::ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)       {Write-Host "The user does not have access to the requested information."}
    #           ([Pinvoke.NERR]::ERROR_INVALID_LEVEL)       {Write-Host "The value specified for the level parameter is not valid."}
    #           ([Pinvoke.NERR]::ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)   {Write-Host 'The specified parameter is not valid.'}
    #           ([Pinvoke.NERR]::ERROR_MORE_DATA)           {Write-Host 'More entries are available. Specify a large enough buffer to receive all entries.'}
    #           ([Pinvoke.NERR]::ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY)   {Write-Host 'Insufficient memory is available.'}
    #           ([Pinvoke.NERR]::NERR_ClientNameNotFound)   {Write-Host 'A session does not exist with the computer name.'}
    #           ([Pinvoke.NERR]::NERR_InvalidComputer)      {Write-Host 'The computer name is not valid.'}
    #           ([Pinvoke.NERR]::NERR_ClientNameNotFound)   {Write-Host 'The user name could not be found.'}                
    #           }
}
}

Get-NetSessions -QueryLevel 0
```

Answer (score 3):

I had long given up on the above and moved onto other things until something picked up my interest again.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2909958/exceptions-in-windows-powershell-other-dynamic-languages-and-dynamical

The above code worked (didn't throw errors) when this very small modification was added:

```
$Info = [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::PtrToStructure($newintptr,$type)
```

to

```
$Info = [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::PtrToStructure($newintptr,[System.Type]$type)
```

If you are interested in using Windows API [this](http://www.harmj0y.net/blog/powershell/powershell-and-win32-api-access/) person has some interesting work and links to some other great resources.

Thanks NullBind for your response, very appreciated.

Comment: This was very helpful and gave me an insight into how to make the following work: [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf([int])
(It throws an error on my machine)
Replacing with [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf([System.Type][int]) is then successful.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this a little and it seems like the only big thing you forgot to do was pass the `$QueryLevel` variable into the “level” parameter of the function when you called it.  Currently the level parameter it statically set to `0` when you call the function.  As a result, when you set the `$Querylevel` to anything other than `0` the structure and the data returned by level `0` don’t match and the script crashes….or something like that.

**This is what you had:**

```
# Call the function<br>
$Result = [pinvoke.Win32Util]::NetSessionEnum($ComputerName,$ComputerSession,$UserName,0,[ref]$ptrInfo,-1,[ref]$EntriesRed,[ref]$TotalRead,[ref]$ResumeHandle)
```

**This is what seemed to work:**

```
# Call the function
$Result = [pinvoke.Win32Util]::NetSessionEnum($ComputerName,$ComputerSession,$UserName, $QueryLevel,[ref]$ptrInfo,-1,[ref]$EntriesRed,[ref]$TotalRead,[ref]$ResumeHandle)
```

I’m a little new to advanced PowerShellery. So if I’m off my rocker let me know, but hopefully that helps.